# Is there a way to link classes from different solutions together in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have multiple solutions for different project I have worked on but the project I am currently working on rely on a class from a previous solution. I was wondering if there was an easy way to link these solutions together so I have access to all the previous classes.

Comment: Not really - solutions are the top-level entity in code organization in Visual Studio.  If the code is to be highly re-usable, then consider making a library (static or DLL) which your future applications are linked against.

Comment: Unless i'm mistaken you should be able to go project->add->existing item (or something like that, I havent used visual studio in about 2 years) and navigate to where the class resides. This will load it into your project without havent to copy it over. I didnt make this an answer because i dont have it installed to be able to verify that this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most maintainable way to do this is to add the source project's header file directory to your target project's include list.

In the project's configuration properties page, go to:

C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories.

If the source project is compiled into a library, dynamic or otherwise, you will need to link with the corresponding .lib file.

To do this, go to "VC++ Directories" and add to the "Library Directories" field the path containing the .lib file.

Note that you can also add your source project's header directory in this page as well.

After that, go to Linker->Input and add your library's .lib file name.

You will now be able to `#include<your_header_file.h>`.

Note that you will need to be careful about the choice of directory, as files with the same names as standard or platform-specific headers will cause problems.

EDIT:

I do not know of a way to avoid editing the VC++ Directories page in the project's property page to add a library directory. Why is this a problem? Things like Intel's C++ composer like to step all over these fields (you have to let it make a mess, then you can clean it up).